# How to save the multiple choice result in DB , and how to retrieve them

Tags: database-design

I have an online research project , and also there is lots of multiple choice question.
for example...↓

```
Q:Which Programming language u like?

1,C

2,C++

3,CSharp

4,VB.NET

5,JAVA

.....

100 , Other
```

I will save the selected item as 1 and unselected as 0

so the result in DB is like↓

```
People      Selected

people1     001000000000000....0

people2     111000000100000....0

people3     001000000000000....1

people4     001000000000000....0

.....
```

And now , If I want to know who how many people only choice the CSharp

I will create the sql query as ↓

```
select count(1) as cnt from table where 1=1 

and  substring('Selected', 1, 1) == '0'

and  substring('Selected', 2, 1) == '0'

and  substring('Selected', 3, 1) == '1'

and  .......
```

but I thought it is too long , and the performance is not very well.

so , please anybody can give me some solution about how to solve the problem?

thanks for your advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 3 table, 1 for people, 2 for languages, 3 that implements many-to-many relationship between first two:
1. Users : `id, name, email,....`;
2. Languages: `id, name, description, ....`;
3. Users_Languages : `user_id, language_id`;

When a user likes the language, insert a record into `Users_Languages`, then he dislikes it, remove the record.
Retrieving is trivial :

```
SELECT u.*, l.name   
 FROM Users u
 INNER JOIN Users_Languages ul ON (ul.user_id = u.id)  
 INNER JOIN Languages l ON (l.id = ul.language_id)
WHERE u.id = 1;
```